# Twitter Bootstrap: Modal Wont Fire

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, plugins, instagram

I'm using this plugin: http://pongstr.github.io/pongstagr.am/#

But I cannot successfully get the model to open up the image in the modal. I'm not sure what it is, but I get this issue in

`'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$('#' + imageId ).modal()')`

Any idea what the issue could be?

Here's the link to the website: http://www.airmanstudios.com/tests/page9/

Comment: Chrome error console gives this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'modal' "

Comment: Are you including the plugin? I don't see it in your source...

Comment: The plugin JS files as well as bootstrap.js are all in this file: http://www.airmanstudios.com/tests/page9/files/stacks_page_page9.js

Comment: How many version of jQuery are you including? What is the value of _ imageId_ before the error in the script?

Comment: Only 1 that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation, I believe you're not including all of the bootstrap files you need.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I couldn't find bootstrap-transition.js, which is definitely required for modal usage: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#transitions

Hope this helps!

Comment: The plugin JS files as well as bootstrap.js are all in this file: http://www.airmanstudios.com/tests/page9/files/stacks_page_page9.js